# error - Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' - my case

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    struct mess {
        let user : String
        let textmessage : String
        var cellId : String
        let view = UIView()
    }

    var message = [mess]()


    @IBOutlet weak var messageCollection: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldZone: UITextField!
    @IBAction func user1Action(_ sender: Any) {
        addMessage(user: "", cell: "customCell")
    }
    func addMessage( user : String , cell : String){
        let text = textFieldZone.text
        let mymessage = mess(user: user, textmessage: text!, cellId: cell)
        message.append(mymessage)
        self.messageCollection.reloadData()
        self.textFieldZone.text = " "
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return message.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let currentMessage = message[indexPath.item]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: currentMessage.cellId, for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell1
        cell.text.text = currentMessage.textmessage
        return cell

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if let messageText = message?[indexPath.item].textmessage {
            let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        }

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

error in line with "if".

what's wrong?

I deleted `?` but it didn't help.

The error is "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'" on the line of the if statement inside the func ***collectionView: layou: sizeForItemAt*** method

Comment: what is error??

Comment: what do you mean by error? crash? compiler error?
also, could you give us more context by giving us the definition of "message"? how is it declared? where? 
Thank you.

Comment: What does message variable hold?

Comment: I mean error compilation.
definition of message 
 ' struct mess {
        let user : String
        let textmessage : String
        var cellId : String
        let view = UIView()
    }
    
    var message = [mess]()
'

Comment: I try to do changing bubbles like in this video - [link](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=132)
but with storyboard :)

Comment: My code - 
' import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, {

    struct mess {
        let user : String
        let textmessage : String
        var cellId : String
        let view = UIView()
    }
    
    var message = [mess]() '

Comment: Ludmila would you mind to edit your question by adding the code you just wrote here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

based on the code that you put on the message, the error is due to the fact that `message` is not an optional, message[indexPath.item] is not an optional as well as message[indexPath.item].textmessage is not an optional.

The if let statement requires an optional on the right side of the equals symbol.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let messageText = message[indexPath.item].textmessage
    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
}
```

If you are not sure that message contains the index, then check message.count

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if message.count > indexPath.item {
        let messageText = message[indexPath.item].textmessage
        let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    }
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: I'm beginner here and as developer. I've changed my question above.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. This code should fix the issue.

Comment: If you found this answer useful and resolutive please consider to mark it as accepted answer for future people who will have the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Error has disappiar but the code dosn't work properly. I need that the text messages were shown with different height depend on more words in them or less. But they are with equal height.

Comment: This is a different issue. You need to open another question for that.

Comment: I see. But i've reached the limit for quastions. Nearest 3 days I can't answer anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need more context to help you there, and as of stack overflow rules this is another question. I have no way to debug your code here.

Comment: Giuseppe, I see. No problem :)

If you have a little time you can find my project here - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5O7THFYi1pkOHpxbGk1MVRCTlk 
I hope I don't breake the rules of this site.

Comment: No you didn't I'll take a look if I have 5 minutes later today. Cheers.

Comment: It would be great if you take a look. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Giuseppe, you forget about me? :)